# Pseudo-inverse with minimal number of non-zero entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matlab, pseudoinverse

I'm looking for a way to compute the pseudo-inverse of a matrix (not the Moore-Penrose, but any other) with the minimal number of non-zero entries (maximum number of zero entries).

In MATLAB, the the `mldivide()` operator does that, but I cannot find any documentation on how this operator evaluates my matrix so that it inds this particular pseudo-inverse. Is there a way to do this "by hand"?

Note: I know, Moore-Penrose minimize the Euclidean norm, but I explicitely do not want to minimize that norm, but to maximize the zero-entries in my pseudo-inverse.

Comment: (Not a direct answer to your question, but complementary information). In fact mldivide(A,B) is nothing else than A\B. Here is an excerpt of a Matlab documentation about the difference with "pinv"; "When the system A*x = b is overdetermined, both algorithms provide a similar answer. When the system is underdetermined, PINV will return the solution x, that has the minimum norm (min NORM(x)). MLDIVIDE will pick a solution which has at most m nonzero components for an m-by-n matrix A". See also the interesting site (http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html)

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie , this is exactly what I was asking for. I know that the mldivide operation does the same as "\" in MATLAB, but I'd like to know how to get to that solution analytically (if that's possible) or even numerically.

Comment: This reference can have some interest for you :(http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/research.html)

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?